# Como salvar uma imagem obtida com: pyautogui.hotkey('Alt','printscreen')?

Tags: python

Preciso salvar imagem obtida pela `pyautogui.hotkey('Alt','printscreen')`

No exemplo abaixo eu utilizei `pyautogui.screenshot()`, mas eu queria pegar um *print* da janela ativa somente.

```
time.sleep(2);
foto = pyautogui.screenshot();
nomeArquivo = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) + '.jpg';
nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.replace('Código: ','');
nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.replace(' - Imagem Ampliada','');
foto.save('C://Tmp//' + nomeArquivo);
```

Comment: Leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) e leia também [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi parcialmente usando

```
pyautogui.screenshot(region=(418,193, 531, 469));
```

#capturei a dimensao da janela

```
regiao=win32gui.GetWindowRect(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow());
```

#fiz as tratativas para dar print na regiao

```
foto = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(regiao[0]+5,regiao[1]+20,regiao[2]-regiao[0]-10,regiao[3]-(regiao[1]+23)));
```